# jQuery - get td cell index of a control

Tags: jquery

** EDIT** I'm very sorry. I need the td index, not the row index.

Using jQuery, how do I get the index of the td `lblName` is in?

```
       <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label id="lblName" />
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: `.index()` gives a zero-based index number, and you have only one row, so its index is `0`. What do you mean by *"the index of the header label"*?

Comment: I apologize, I need the td index, not row index.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

***Update for updated question:***

```
$('#lblName').parent().index();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('lblName').parentNode.cellIndex
```

---

***Original answer:***

Use `.index()`.

```
$('#lblName').closest('tr').index();
```

The `.index()` method has a few different use patterns.

This one means *"take the first element matched by the selector, and return its zero based index of its position among its siblings"*.

---

Or natively, do this...

```
document.getElementById('lblName').parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex
```

---

Or combine the two...

```
$('#lblName').closest('tr')[0].rowIndex;
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! It worked perfectly. Can you recommend a good book on jquery?

Comment: @user349308: You may want to take a look at the [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) on jQuery's site. Also, just run through the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/). If you type a word, like "index", into the search field toward the top, it'll narrow the list for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $('#lblName').closest('tr').index();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table tr").index($("#lblName").parents("tr:first"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this piece of code would be of any help.

You can use the index() with parentsUntill() to the parent TR element of that TD.

example http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/bGvHZ/

```
$('#lblName').parentsUntil('tr').index()
```